# INSERT INTO SECOND TABLE USING WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: mysql, sql

'Routes' table includes same route upto 6 times, only want to keep record with latest 'File date' & copy these into 'Routes2' table

Heidi SQL

```
TRUNCATE TABLE temp.Routes2 
INSERT INTO temp.Routes2 
SELECT * 
from temp.Routes 
where temp.`File Date` = select max(t2.`File Date`) from temp.Routes as t2
LIMIT 100
```

get SQL error 1064

> Sure, I just miss understood the syntax

Many Thanks
Simon

Comment: Can you add the full and exact error message to your question?

Answer (score 2):

You want parenthesis & reference from outerquery to make it correlated subquery :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM temp.Routes as t1
WHERE temp.`File Date` = (select max(t2.`File Date`) 
                          from temp.Routes as t2
                          where t1.col = t2.col
                         );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below -

```
    INSERT INTO temp.Routes2 
    SELECT * 
    from temp.Routes a
    where a.`File Date` = (select max(t2.`File Date`) from temp.Routes as t2)
    order by temp.`File Date` limit 100
```

Comment: Thanks, fa06, get error message SQL error (1054) Unknown column 'temp.File Date' in 'where clause'

Thanks Simon